# Prevent first row being deleted in table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to stop all the rows being deleted from my table view by user so at least one row is always present.

Im still geting to grips with programming and objective c.

Heres what I tried:

```
  if (indexPath.section != 0 | editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
  [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.circuits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  [self.appDelegate saveContext];
  [self.circuits removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

then

```
if (indexPath.section > 1 | editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.circuits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.appDelegate saveContext];
    [self.circuits removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

That had no effect in that I can still delete the first row. So then I tried

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    return NO;

return YES;
}
```

Still cant  prevent the first row from being deleted

Comment: Single pipe | indicates bitwise OR. You mean logical OR, which is ||. What you're doing might work, but it's still wrong.

Comment: thanks for the tip, thats noted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) method `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` and return `NO` for the `indexPath.row` `0`.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.row > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your code into
 `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    return NO;
    else
    return YES;

    }
```

It will surely help you